# Cell references are not working, they appear to be strings and not references, how to fix?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Usually, if you have a formula that references a sheet, like `Sheet2!B2:B` and you decided to change the name of that Sheet to "Sales", the formula updates the Sheetname to `Sales!B2:B`.

I have a formula where my references don't seem to be working, I keep getting the `#ERROR`. I am referencing a Sheet, it looks like it is correct, I change the name of the Sheet to something else, and the formula doesn't update the reference. That makes me think that it isn't actually reading this as a cell reference but as a string instead.

I have this sample, which has the working formula: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iLMCLIuXSjX1v4VvpdVI6omWXe3p0_s_eCpjsQ3GsbE/edit#gid=1544764194

In my actual sheet with real data, the same formula, with the correct sheet names, returns `#ERROR` as described above. I don't understand why the references are not working.

How to make sure the reference is an actual reference and not some string?

Update: So the issue seemed to have been, that in the german version, formulas use the semicolon to separate arguments and not commas... Instead I now get a different Error message now:

Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col2

Formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(
{
'anzahl-schulen'!A:A;
IFERROR(VLOOKUP('anzahl-schulen'!A:A;hochschulen!A:B;2;0);-1)
};
"select Col1,COUNT(Col1),Col2,COUNT(Col1)/Col2 where Col1<>'' group by Col1,Col2 label COUNT(Col1)'amount',Col2'total amount',COUNT(Col1)/Col2'percentage'"
))
```

Edit: I was told that someone else will take over this task. I will keep the question up, if someone wants to answer and help future people that stumble upon this issue.

Comment: Have you re-checked if the columns selected are okay? Is it possible to reproduce with the example sheet you shared?

Comment: I tried my best with my sample. The sample formula came first, which I then tried to apply to my production data, but that didn't work. I also don't know how to reproduce the issue.
I was also told, that someone else will take over the data analysing, so... I guess it doesn't matter anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I took your sample sheet and changed the Sheet! name to anzahl-schulen and the back to see what would happen.

So far everything seems ok to me.

I would try and re-type the formulas just to make sure they are referencing the right cells (I also wouldn't type the cell reference it self, I prefer to select them and let Google Sheets deal with the typing).

[image]

Comment: It turns out the issue was, that formulars are written differently in the european version, so instead of commas it is semicolon, and the seperate within `{...}` is a backslash instead of a comma.